# Editing Contacts info in WP7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, outlook

Recently in my Country (Egypt) They decided to edit the phone numbers prefix to add an extra number to each cell phone prefix (ex. 011->0111 )

I want to make an application that will handle that editing programmatically for me

I know I can retrieve contacts info one by one and I can save new info to a certain contact through the phone tasks (phone number chooser task and phone number save task)...

till now my best shot is to make the user choose contacts one by one and for each one I add an extra phone number which is the new number, but cannot delete the old one, and cannot loop through all contacts.

is there's a way to programmatically do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is not. You're better off to export all your contacts though Windows Live or your Google Account, and edit it from there.

Google can export to a Microsoft Excel document, that you could easily do search&replace in. (Or CSV)