# manipulate contacts in WP7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I want to make an application that manipulating contacts. I developed listing contacts in listbox. Also I developed saving contacts by using SaveContactTask. However I don't know how to develop edit and delete contacts. 
Is that impossible??? If possible, please tell me how to develop.

Answer (score 0):

It is NOT available.
Imagine that some bad application removes user's contact list. That would be terrible.
For this reason, Windows Phone OS does not provide the feature to developer.

similar question here: [Editing Contacts info in WP7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7663304/editing-contacts-info-in-wp7)